# Flaw in conditional expectation shortcut

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

The problem is simple: given 2 independent uniform random variables $X, Y$ over $[a, b]$, find $\mathbb{E}[X - Y \ | \ X > Y]$.

My intuitive approach is to first fix $Y = y$, then for this specific case, we have
$$\mathbb{E}[X - y \ | \ X > y] = \mathbb{E}[X - y \ | \ X \in [y, b]] = \dfrac{b+y}{2} -y = \dfrac{b-y}{2}$$

Now we can integrate over $Y = y \in [a, b]$ to get:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X - Y \ | \ X > Y] 
&=\int_a^b \mathbb{E}[X - y \ | \ X \in [y, b]] \cdot \dfrac{1}{b-a} \ \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \int_a^b \dfrac{b-y}{2} \cdot \dfrac{1}{b-a} \ \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \dfrac{b-a}{4}
\end{align}
$$
which is wrong, as the correct answer (verified computationally) should be $\dfrac{b-a}{\color{red}3}$.

What is the flaw in my logic?

Comment: Both are wrong. Without independnece of $X$ and $Y$ (or some other information)  there is no answer to this question.

Comment: Right, edited the question. $X, Y$ are iid, uniform random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to claim that $\mathsf E(X-Y\mid X>Y)=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X-y\mid X>y)_{y:=Y})$  but

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X-y\mid X>y)_{y:=Y})&=\int_a^bf_Y(y)\dfrac{\int_y^b~(x-y)~f_{X}(x)~\mathrm d x}{\mathsf P(X>y)}~\mathrm d y\tag{RHS}\\&=\int_a^b \dfrac{1}{b-a}\int_y^b\dfrac{(x-y)}{(b-y)}\mathrm d x\mathrm d y\\&=\int_a^b\dfrac{b-y}{2(b-a)}\mathrm d y\\&=\dfrac{b-a}{4}\end{align}$$

Where as:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X-Y\mid X>Y) &=\dfrac{\int_a^b\int_y^b (x-y)~f_{X}(x) f_Y(y)~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y}{\mathsf P(X>Y)}\tag{LHS}\\&=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_a^b\int_y^b\dfrac{(x-y)}{(b-a)^2}~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y\\&=\int_a^b \dfrac{(b-y)^2}{2(b-a)^2}~\mathrm dy\\&=\dfrac{b-a}{3}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

You are misapplying the rule, valid for $X$, $Y$ independent,
$$E[h(X,Y)]=\int E[h(X,y)]f_Y(y)\,dy.$$ The rule is valid when evaluating the expectation of a function $h(X,Y)$ of $X$ and $Y$, such as $h(X,Y):=X-Y$, but it does not apply to $h(X,Y):= X-Y\mid X>Y$, which is not a function of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the following:

$$
\mathbb{E}[g(X,Y) \ | \ r(X,Y) ] = \iint g(x,y) \ f(x,y \ | \ r(x,y)) \ \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}y
$$
where:

- $g(X,Y)$ is a function of $X, Y$, in my case $g(X,Y) := X - Y$
- $r(X,Y)$ is the region we condition on, in my case $r(X,Y) := X > Y$

Now we need the conditioned PDF:
$$
f(x,y  \ | \ x > y) = \dfrac{f(x,y)}{p(X > Y)} = \dfrac{2}{(b-a)^2}
$$
for $a \leq y \leq x \leq b$.

and we can proceed with the integration:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X - Y \ | \ X > Y ] 
&= \int_a^b \int_y^b (x-y) \ f(x,y \ | \ x > y) \ \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}y \\
&=  \int_a^b \int_y^b (x-y) \ \dfrac{2}{(b-a)^2} \ \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \dfrac{b-a}{3}  \ \ \blacksquare
\end{align} 
$$